# No member named 'clock' in the global namespace when using FFmpeg pod

Tags: ios, xcode, ffmpeg, cocoapods

My app (iOS 7+, Xcode 6) uses CocoaPods for its dependencies. One of the dependencies is [FFmpeg](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg).

When I build my app I get several similar looking issues like

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ctime:60:9:
>   No member named 'clock' in the global namespace; did you mean 'flock'?

I learned that this is because FFmpeg includes `time.h` file in `libavutil` subfolder. This `time.h` hides system `time.h` from the compiler and thus the errors.

I tried to manually rename FFmpeg's time.h to something else and *this helps*. Now I want to do that automatically and in a way that will survive next 'pod update'.

I tried to add libavutil to `Sub-Directories to Exclude In Recursive Searches` but this doesn't help at all.

I tried to remove "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FFmpeg/libavutil" from `Header Search Paths` and it didn't help either.

I know there are `prepare_command` and `post_install` hooks one can use in his Podfile but unfortunately I don't know if these are helpful in my case.

So, how can I exclude time.h in libavutil of FFmpeg pod from header search paths (I don't mind to rename or even remove the time.h)?

Answer (score 7):

For people who have the same issue with ffmpeg's `time.h`:

You might search the system's `time.h` and include it manually in the ffmpeg's `time.h`:

open ffmpeg's `time.h` (in `libavutil`) and insert `#include </usr/include/time.h>` in the beginning.

Of course this is just a lazy workaround, but it's an easy way to include both `time.h` headers.

Comment: For those who had installed Xcode and didn't find the time.h header into mentioned path the right include could be:
#include </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/time.h>

Comment: I don't know why, but I had to add `#include </usr/include/time.h>` in /usr/local/include/time.h

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another solution, as the provided ones were not working fully for me. What worked well for me:

1. rename libavutil/time.h to libavutil/fftime.h
2. in this file add a line (near other includes) `#include <time.h>`

I think it's a more reliable and elastic solution, even if it requires more changes in ffmpeg's headers. Will be testing this solution for coulpe of projects.

Cheers, Teo

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude FFmpeg's `time.h` from public headers of the pod in your `Podfile` in case if you don't use functions from this file, such as: av_gettime, av_gettime_relative, av_gettime_relative_is_monotonic, av_usleep.

**Podfile:**

```rb
target 'YourApp' do
    project 'YourApp'
    ...
    pod 'FFmpeg', '= 2.8.3'
end

pre_install do |installer|
  installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
        # FFmpeg: Fix with <time.h>
        if pod.name == 'FFmpeg'
            pod.file_accessors.each do |fa|
                fa.spec.exclude_files = 'ffmpeg-ios-static-libs/include/**/time.h'
            end
        end
  end
end
```